# virtualbox sdk get stdout

Tags: python, sdk, virtualbox, virtualhost

Need help. I'am trying using Virtualbox SDK 5.1 on python 2.7 and I don't know how get stdout after execute command in vm guest os. This my code:

```
BASIC_SNAPSHOT = 'clear'
TARGET_NAME = 'ubuntu-server-1404'

vbm = VirtualBoxManager()
vbox = vbm.vbox
mach = vbox.findMachine(TARGET_NAME)

session = vbm.getSessionObject(vbox)

def run_test():
    mach.lockMachine(session, 1)

    guest = session.console.guest
    #gs = session.console.guest.createSession('t4ks', 'Qwerty123', '', '')
    gs = guest.createSession('t4ks', 'Qwerty123', '', '')
    gs.waitFor(1, 3000)
    args = ["-l", "-a"]
    gp = gs.processCreate('/bin/ls', args, None, (5,), 30)
    gp.waitFor(1, 3000)

    pid = gp.PID
    #print gp.PID
    data = gp.read(1, 2000, 100)
    print data
    session.unlockMachine()
```

In data variable nothing write :(

Answer (score 0):

I also get stdout after executing cmd in VM. Try and adapt the below code I'm using:

```
import subprocess    
def parse_stdout():
        checkCommand = [getVBoxManage(), "guestproperty", "enumerate", computer, "--pattern", "*/IP"]
        # ignore the above cmd :)
        print checkCommand
        parsable_stdout = subprocess.Popen(checkCommand, stdout = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
        return parsable_stdout
```

Hope it helps.